# Can I use DB::table('tags')... outside of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent ORM in my Zend application. This allows me to do things like:

```
$capsule = new Capsule();
$capsule->addConnection( $config );
$capsule->bootEloquent();
.
.
.
$question = new Question();      
$question->user_id = $user->id;
$question->title = $params->title;
$question->content = $params->content;
$question->save();
```

However, I want to do the following to allow me to perform multiple inserts:

```
DB::table('tags')->insert($values);
```

..but ofcourse I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found ...
```

Can I use these DB::* methods outside of Laravel? I've had a look in my /vendor/Illuminate/Database directory but I don't really know which class it's referring to.

Answer (score 2):

First you would need to refer to the namespace where "Capsule" class is located in. At the top of the script add:

```
<?php use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
```

Then you can call:

```
Capsule::table('part')->where('id', '=', '1')->get();
```

Similarly in your case try using:

```
Capsule::table('tags')->insert($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DB` is refferring to `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` so if you add at top of your file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager as DB;
```

you should be able to use `DB`

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a namespace other than Illuminate simply you can use it as \DB it will look outside of your namespace and will find the DB Facade

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this worked:

```
Tag::insert($values);
```

Don't know why I didn't think to try this. Thanks anyway.